# collision with rectangle.intersects [Java]

Tags: java, collision-detection, rectangles

So, I'm trying to make a collision for the walls in my game using Rectangles, and I decided to try and use an ArrayList to store the rectangles of each wall, and I make the entire field a wall, and all I want to do is remove three of the walls, so I'm doing shapeList.remove(0) to try and remove the first wall at 0,0 but its not working, I don't know if i'm doing it wrong, or if theres a better way, but I could use some help solving this issue, here is the code.

```
    public void walls(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++) {
        for (int wallsX = 0; wallsX < 750; wallsX += 95) {
            for (int wallsY = 0; wallsY < 750; wallsY += 95) {
                shapeList.add(new Rectangle(wallsX, wallsY, 95, 95));
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
                g.drawRect(wallsX, wallsY, 95, 95);
            }
        }
    }
    shapeList.remove(0); //I want to remove wall at 0,0... but not working
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 95, 95);
    g.fillRect(95, 0, 95, 95);
    g.fillRect(0, 95, 95, 95);

    for (int i = 0; i < shapeList.size(); i++) {
        if (intersectsBox(getRectangle(), shapeList.get(i))) {
            isInsideWalls = true;

        }else{
            isInsideWalls = false;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: When i run this code, this error appears:

```
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Rectangle.intersects(Unknown Source)
    at bombermangame.Game.intersectsBox(Game.java:122)
    at bombermangame.Game.walls(Game.java:147)
    at bombermangame.Game.paintComponent(Game.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: When you say its not working, could you provide more info? Is there an error or is the wrong wall getting deleted?

Comment: I get the feeling there are 63 walls with coordinate (0,0) because this `(int i = 0; i < 63; i++)` forces 63 loops before entering the inner 2 for loops.  I believe at the end of your 63 loops, all you do is remove one of the rectangles with coordinates at (0,0).

Comment: The thing is, I have it so, if the player Rect intersects the Walls Rect, then it either + or - the players x or y value, depending on how the player intersects it. And for some reason, it keeps saying the player is always in a wall, even though the player spawns at 0,0. even if i change  'if (intersectsBox(getRectangle(), shapeList.get(i))) {', and make the i into lets say a 4, no matter where the player is, it says hes in a wall. the full code if you need to see it is here: [CODE](http://pastebin.com/DxhF3hhj)

Comment: Don't you have walls that cover the entire 750 x 750 screen?  Secondly, I get the impression there are 63 walls stacked on each other.  So yeah, it makes sense that the player is always in a wall since even when you remove the first wall at (0,0), you still have another 62 rectangles at coordinates (0,0).

Comment: How would I go about making it so, it only makes 1 wall, on 0,0 not stacking? change 63 to 1?

Comment: Well, that make sense since tile 4 wouldnt be at (0,0).  Tile 4 would be at location (0, 285).

Comment: Why do you have a for loop that iterates 63 times, thats what I don't get though?

Comment: Because it was suppose to hold 63 walls in the List, but I guess thats not how i do it

Comment: Well based on your for loop, 750 divided by 95 = ~7.  Now since you have 2 of those loops that iterate from 0 to 750 incrementing by 95, your 2 inner loop already iterates 49 times (basically 7 x 7).  Now consider you have an outer for loop that iterates 63 times.  So the number of objects inside your list is 49 x 63.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75341/discussion-between-joejoethemonkey-and-porororo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following loop below will need to be removed as it creates 63 copies of your wall grid.  What this means is that every single coordinate you specify will contains 63 rectangles.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++) {
```

The reason removing the for loop will fix at least one of your problems is because when you remove the first rectangle, there are 62 rectangles left at the same coordinate.

All you will need to create your list of walls is the following:

```
for (int wallsX = 0; wallsX < 750; wallsX += 95) {
      for (int wallsY = 0; wallsY < 750; wallsY += 95) {
           shapeList.add(new Rectangle(wallsX, wallsY, 95, 95));
           g.setColor(Color.blue);
           g.drawRect(wallsX, wallsY, 95, 95);
      }
}
```

Now once you apply `shapeList.remove(0);`

There should be no walls at coordinate (0,0) anymore.

There may be other errors in your code that I am unaware of though.  I've only looked at your code that you've provided in your question.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem, but I had a second problem, I accidentally put this all inside the Update() method, so it kept running over and over, creating thousands of walls..... that wasn't that good. But this also helped me, so thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :), I too improve myself by helping others.

Comment: I have 1 more question, [Pic](http://prntscr.com/6uac05) I am remaking bomberman for my coding class, (the same code i sent before) and I don't know which box is which, except i know these 3 by testing, how do i figure out the rest?

Comment: The 3 that are labeled in the Pic, i took of the game, those are the 3 wall locations in the ArrayList i know of. And i'm not sure how to figure out the rest of them.

Comment: You sort of made it difficult for yourself by making a 1 dimensional list to represent your 2 dimensional grid.  You should have used a 2 dimension array or some sort of 2 dimensional data structure to represent your grid.  Believe me, it makes finding every wall on your grid 100x easier.

Comment: An example would be instead of having lets say a list of 64 walls, u might have a list of 8 x 8 walls.  Something like this: `Shape [][] shape = new Shape[8][8];` to represent your 2 dimensional grid.